# Populating columns with a value based on a condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing fields called 'Category' and 'TotalTime'. When I run a query, I need to generate two additional temporary columns called 'Cat1Time'and 'Cat2Time'.

If the total time in a row is 4 hours and it is category 1, it should display a '4' under the Cat1Time column. If the total time in a row is 4 hours and it is category 1, it should display a '4' under the 'Cat2Time' column. Is there a way to do this?

```
EntryID | Category | Cat1Time | Cat2Time
2       |  1       |   4      |    
3       |  2       |          |   4
4       |  1       |   2.5    |   




Select EntryID, Category, TotalTime AS Cat1Time 
WHERE Category =1, TotalTime as Cat2Time where Category = 2 
from LogEntry
```

Anyways, I know that won't work... it's just to give you an idea what I am trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mihai, I was just trying to figure make my post appear like that. Thank you so very much!!!!!

Comment: I dont understand your logic,how do you calculate totaltime?

Comment: The total time is user entered. The user could enter any integer they want - it is not a calculated field. I need to figure out if it is total time for category number 1 or category number 2. Total time will be entered, but not displayed in the table. Sorry I didn't clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statement:

```
SELECT EntryID, Category, TotalTime,
    CASE WHEN Category = 1 THEN
        TotalTime
    ELSE
        NULL
    END AS Cat1Time,
    CASE WHEN Category = 2 THEN
        TotalTime
    ELSE
        NULL
    END AS Cat2Time 
FROM LogEntry
```

Comment: OMG! I can't believe it was so simple. Thank you SO MUCH, Rhumborl!